# CSS Menu active/current link not working correctly

Tags: html, css

Here is the CSS code i have for my navigation menu:

```
#cssmenu *{
    z-index: 999
}
#cssmenu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; }
#cssmenu li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu a { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {list-style: none;}
#cssmenu a {text-decoration: none;}
#cssmenu {
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: #74a5d4; /* main background color */
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: #FFFFFF; /* main link text color */
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 16px 20px;
-webkit-transition: color .15s;
   -moz-transition: color .15s;
     -o-transition: color .15s;
        transition: color .15s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: #ffffff; /* main link text hover color */
    background-color:#c3d021; /* main link background hover color */
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #74a5d4; /*submenu link background color */
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    width: 180px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
     -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
        transition: all .3s .1s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50px;
    visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(250,250,250) transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul > li { position: relative;}
#cssmenu ul ul a{
    color: #FFFFFF; /* submenu link text color */
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #74a5d4; /*submenu background color (behind links) */
    padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
    display: block;
-webkit-transition: background-color .1s;
   -moz-transition: background-color .1s;
     -o-transition: background-color .1s;
        transition: background-color .1s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover {
    background-color:#c3d021; /*background color that shows on the main menu link when hovering over the sub menu */
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a{
    color: #000000; /* main menu link hover text color */
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 206px;
    background-color:#74a5d4;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 160px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s;
     -o-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; left: 196px; visibility: visible;}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover{
    background-color: #c3d021; /*submenu link hover color */
    color:#000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
    background-color:#c3d021;
    color:#000000;
}
```

The id at the bottom:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
        background-color:#c3d021;
        color:#000000;
    }
```

creates an active/current link for when the page i active. its changing the background colour of the link but not the text color. what am i doing wrong?

Here is the HTML for the active link:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/home.php"><span>Homepage</span></a></li>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the `color` to the `<a>` itself not the `<li>`

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
color: black;
}
```

Also, for:

```
#cssmenu *{
position: relative; 
z-index: 999
}
```

You forgot to include a position property, as [z-index](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) can only create a stacking-context on elements that have relative or absolute/fixed positioning - the exception is css3 [flex items](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/):

*"Flex items paint exactly the same as inline blocks [CSS21], except that ‘order’-modified document order is used in place of raw document order, and ‘z-index’ values other than ‘auto’ create a stacking context even if ‘position’ is ‘static’."*

Answer (score 1):

instead try:

```
a:link {
    //your styles
}a:visited {
    //your styles
}a:hover {
    //your styles
}a:hover {
    //your styles
}
```

and make sure that the order is maintained...

Comment: I think you meant a:active for the last one.